# Impersonate another user in Visual SourceSafe

Tags: visual-sourcesafe, impersonation

We had an employee leave the company, and they left some files checked out in our VSS database.  What is the best way to impersonate that user, so I can release those files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Within ssadmin you can reset their VSS password (so that you know what their VSS password is, so that you can then log in as them using their password).

Answer (score 0):

You could try logging in as an admin and undoing their checkout. You'd lose any work they did locally but if you only care about releasing the file lock it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

The admin can undo the checkout.

Comment: OK - I just ran into this same problem and finally remembered the details.  You need to login to VSS (not the VSS Admin) as an administrator.  From there you will be able to undo the checkout of any user's files.